# ParserError 5 (SeismicXML)

Tags: iphone, xml, parsing

I have modified SeismicXML to parse my own custom xml feed. Every attribute is parsed correctly up until reaching the end of the first element.

The xml:

```
<item>
    <title>Un post nou</title>
    <desc>Que diu alguna cosa</desc>
    <foto>photo.jpg</foto>
    <lat>41.36441</lat>
    <long>1.75361</long>
</item>
```

My object has 5 properties:
    @property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *titol;
    @property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *descripcio;
    @property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *urlFoto;
    @property (nonatomic,retain) double latitud;
    @property (nonatomic,retain) double longitud;

When my NSXMLPares reaches `</Item>` it throws:

> NSXMLSParserErrorDomain

with Code=5.

Following the NSXML Parser Reference, this error is:

> NSXMLParserPrematureDocumentEndError->The document ended unexpectedly.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I bet the problem comes from the XML which, in fact, is a PHP file, but I'm not sure.

Any help from the community would be appreciated.

Comment: Is that your entire XML document, or have you only shown one item as an example?

Comment: I have only shown first item. In fact it's just a test xml with 2 items following the structure above. There's nothing else: <item>...</item><item>...</item>. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The parse error you're getting is because the XML parser requires there to be a single top level node around all your items.  Try creating your XML something like this:

```
<feed>
    <item>
        ...
    </item>
    <item>
        ...
    </item>
</feed>
```

Comment: Excellent! Many thanks, you have saved me hours of brainstorming!